# Dieharder dab_monobit2 test fails - all other tests pass - TRNG

Tags: unit-testing, random, trng

I am currently testing some RNG numbers from a TRNG using the dieharder test suite. I got around 380MB binary test data from the TRNG and all tests pass except one test - the dab_monobit2 test (test 209) and I just don't know why.

As far as I understood the dab_monobit2 tests does exactly the same as the other monobit test (test 100) it counts the 1's and 0's within a specific range and checks if its more or less 50:50 . What is exactly the difference between the monobit test (test 100) and the dab_monobit2 test? And what does it say about my TRNG?

Here it the output of the monobit test and the dab_monobit2 test:

> sts_monobit|   1|    100000|     100|0.74709531|  PASSED
>   dab_monobit2|  12|  65000000|       1|1.00000000|  FAILED

Comment: What command/flags did you use? `dab_monobit2` is very sensitive to rewinds and requires at least 260 MB of binary data.